# I keep getting Logicals after using the summarise function I.e my reponse after running the code below is TRUE,FALSE. I need the numeric values

Tags: r, data-analysis, data-cleaning, exploratory-data-analysis

Trying to create a table to show BMI under different categories

```
weight %>% 

  group_by(Id) %>% 
  select(Id,BMI) %>% 

   summarise(
   healthy = BMI<25 ,
   not_obese = BMI>25 & BMI<29.9,
   low_risk_obesity = BMI>30 & BMI<34.9,
   moderate_risk_obesity = BMI>35 & BMI<39.9,
   High_risk_obesity =  BMI>40,
   count_records = n(),
   ) %>% 

     view()
```

desired output should be like this in a table column :healthy, not_obese,moderate_risk_obesity,high_risk_obesity followed by the numeric values under each row

healthy --- 20, 19, 21.2, 23, 24
not_obese --- 25, 27, 25.5, 27, 28

Comment: Thanks for your swift response, I just tried that but it gave me the sum of the logical response. I am looking for  the exact values of BMI within the specified range

Comment: Thanks for your input, i have made modifications to the question, pls check

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wanting to use the `cut()` function to provide the groupings and then you can use the summarize function with `toString()` to get your desired output.

```
#create some random data
weight <- data.frame(BMI=round(runif(50, 10, 60), 1))

#cut into desire groupings
weight$status <- cut(weight$BMI, breaks=c(0, 25, 30, 35, 40, 200), labels=c("healthy", 'not_obese', "low_risk_obesity", "moderate_risk_obesity", "High_risk_obesity"))

library(dplyr)
#create a string with the values
#I don't see a purpose in this part
weight %>% group_by(status) %>% summarize(count=n(), values = toString(BMI))

# A tibble: 5 × 3
  status                count values                                                                                                        
  <fct>                 <int> <chr>                                                                                                         
1 healthy                  15 20.8, 12.4, 16.2, 13.3, 10.2, 20.5, 15.8, 11, 10.3, 21.7, 20.3, 23.5, 15.2, 14.8, 17.6                        
2 not_obese                 6 25.8, 28.3, 26.1, 29.1, 27, 28.4                                                                              
3 low_risk_obesity          6 30.5, 32.5, 30.5, 32.8, 34.5, 32.9                                                                            
4 moderate_risk_obesity     4 35.2, 40, 39.4, 39.3                                                                                          
5 High_risk_obesity        19 53.8, 58.5, 42.8, 55.1, 42.5, 59.4, 47.7, 55.8, 50.2, 47.2, 50.9, 59, 50.3, 41.3, 50.2, 53.4, 54.7, 46.8, 53.3
```